# My custom backend codes shows up when i try to view my website

Tags: custom-field, link-category

I created subcategories using custom HTML tags under static content>backend editor>Text block. For some reasons when I tried to view my website. I checked on the subcategories I created and all I see is the actual custom Html codes.